# What is the difference between JDBC Driver and Driver class?

Tags: java, jdbc

Does driver means the all classes in **ojdbc14.jar** and **classes12.jar** or **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver**? Does the word **driver** has two contexts in JDBC?

In the IBM website I found,

> The JDBC API defines the Java interfaces and classes that programmers
>   use to connect to databases and send queries. A JDBC driver implements
>   these interfaces and classes for a particular DBMS vendor.

and in the Oracle documentation of `OracleDriver` class

> The `registerDriver()` method takes as input a "driver" class, that is,
>   a class that implements the `java.sql.Driver` interface, as is the case
>   with OracleDriver.

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle JDBC driver is bundled in ojdbc14.jar. The main class is oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, which can be viewed as a starting point.

The JAR file also contains other classes for binding to different data types (e.g. Date, and Long), connection pooling, data source, etc, which are used by the class OracleDriver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is whether all those classes together are called as driver or just the oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is?

Comment: All those classes together constitute the Oracle JDBC driver. Just like if you write a large application named *Foo* in Java, this application will have many classes, and one of them, containing the `main()` method, could also be named *Foo*.

Answer (score 0):

The term "driver class" is used to mean the class implementing the `java.sql.Driver` interface, as the text you have quoted says. We need to know which class is the driver class because we need to load that class, because it is the entry point for the driver to install itself or be installed as a JDBC driver in Java. That's why there is this terminology. I admit that it's not the clearest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as JB Nizet said, oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is the main/starting class. In Object Oriented Programming, you model functions for different purposes in different classes. For example, when the main class of the driver see a Java Date and need to convert it to an Oracle date object, it calls another class specialized for this purpose. Each data type is handled by a different class, and things like connection pooling/data sources are all separate classes managed in separate packages. Together they form a working JDBC driver.